# Call on object getting non-null once

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android

I need to make one simple thing: when my field, which previous state was null, becomes non-null do some stuff once. If it wasn't null beforehand, the submission should also perform once. For this I created this code:

```
Observable.just(object).filter(new Func1<Object, Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean call(Object o) {
                return o != null;
            }
        }).subscribe(new Action1<Object>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object o) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Object is non-null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Although it doesn't work. What should I do?

Any help would be kindly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that your object is not null? I tested your code and it worked fine for me, you can add a `System.out.println(o != null);` in the filter's call and check it.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use `BehaviorSubject` to store a value and apply `distinctUntilChanged` with a null check to react to changes:

```
BehaviorSubject<Object> bs = BehaviorSubject.create();

bs.distinctUntilChanged(v -> v != null)
.doOnNext(v -> System.out.println(v))
.subscribe();

bs.onNext(1);
bs.onNext(2);
bs.onNext(null);
bs.onNext(null);
bs.onNext(3);
```